# how can I initialize an enum from an Int or Byte?

Tags: scala, enumeration

I have an enum like this:

```
object Ops extends Enumeration {
  val one = Value(0x01)
  val two = Value(0x02)
  val three = Value(0x03)
  val four = Value(0x04)
}
```

I want to say

```
Byte someByte = functionThatReturnsAByte
val op = Ops.valueOf(someByte)
```

The only method close is withName which only takes a String.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Ops(someByte)
```

will do the trick.